# What do the markings on this IC mean?

Tags: integrated-circuit, markings

Its package is SO-8. The markings are "L241" and "G780". I searched these on the web but found nothing. Then I looked at the schematic of the board. The IC is a digital temperature sensor with part number MAX6657YMS+. I have no idea what the markings mean, though I'm curious to know!

[image]

Comment: Maxim has a topmark search on their site: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/packaging/topmark.html?q=lg&action=topMark
That mark isn't showing up as a MAX6657 nor does doing a reverse search for the part number show that mark.

Comment: Markings on the tops often will mean "nothing" to you.  Often they are just date and lot codes.

Comment: The datasheet for this part also does not show package markings. Sometimes manufacturers will explain package markings, sometimes they do not. They are often for silicon revision, lot numbers, date codes, and proprietary info.

Comment: It is possibly deliberately marked with a number that you cannot trace back to what it is. It may be a part number assigned to that part by the manufacturer. Generally if skilled using reverse engineering you may figure out what it might be.